# How to set/replace values in xml with Python etree lxml xpath?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I want to parse an AndroidManifest.xml with Python2.7 and etree/lxml/xpath to find attribute names and to get and **set** their values.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.wearable.timer" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="20"
          android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"
        android:allowBackup="true">
</application>
</manifest>
```

On Bash I used xmlstarlet for this:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u '/manifest/application/@android:allowBackup' -v true AndroidManifest.xml
```

This is what I have so far:

```
from lxml import etree
NS = {'android' : 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'}
tree = etree.parse('AndroidManifest.xml')
# get values
print tree.xpath("///@android:allowBackup", namespaces=NS)[0]
print tree.xpath("///@android:minSdkVersion", namespaces=NS)[0]
# set values ?
# write changes back to file ?
print etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
```

This prints true, 20 and then the whole unchanged xml document.

- **How do I set the values for allowBackup and minSdkVersion to false and 19, respectively?**

Bonus:

- How do I add android:allowBackup or android:minSdkVersion if they are not already present?
- How do I write the changes back to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.wearable.timer" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="20"
          android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"
        android:allowBackup="true">
</application>
</manifest>"""
```

To set the values, find the node then access it's attrib dict then set the new value on it's attribute by using [*QName*](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.QName-class.html) where the first arg is the namespace URI  and the second is the attribute name:

```
import lxml.etree as et

tree = et.fromstring(xml)
# holds namespace mappings
nsmap = tree.nsmap
# get prefix URI
android = tree.nsmap["android"]

# find app and set the attribute value.
tree.find("application", nsmap).attrib[et.QName(android, "allowBackup")] = "false"
tree.find("uses-sdk", nsmap).attrib[et.QName(android, "minSdkVersion")] = "17"
print(et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

Which gives you:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.android.wearable.timer">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
<application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" android:allowBackup="false">
</application>
</manifest>
```

To read and write from and to a file, the logic is the same just at the end you [write](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write) passing in the filename and any other args:

```
import lxml.etree as et
from StringIO import StringIO

tree = et.parse(StringIO(xml))
root = tree.getroot()
nsmap = root.nsmap
android = nsmap["android"]

tree.find("application", nsmap).attrib[et.QName(android, "allowBackup")] = "false"
tree.find("uses-sdk", nsmap).attrib[et.QName(android, "minSdkVersion")] = "17"

# write the updated html to "new.xml"
tree.write("new.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```

new.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.android.wearable.timer">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
<application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" android:allowBackup="false">
</application>
</manifest>
```

You now know how to write the changes, as for missing attributes it works as is, if the value exists we update it, if not we create it:

```
# no minSDk...
In [31]: !cat  test.xml<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.wearable.timer" >
<uses-sdk  android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"
        android:allowBackup="true">
</application>
</manifest>
In [32]: tree = et.parse("test.xml")

In [33]: root = tree.getroot()

In [34]: nsmap = root.nsmap

In [35]: android = nsmap["android"]

In [36]: tree.find("uses-sdk", nsmap).attrib[et.QName(android, "minSdkVersion")] = "17"

In [37]: tree.write("test.xml", encoding="utf-8")

# New attribute and value created.
In [38]: !cat  test.xml<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.android.wearable.timer">
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="17"/>
<application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" android:allowBackup="true">
</application>
</manifest>
In [39]:
```